# Requirements to show up in Network Neighborhood

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

**What are the requirements for a Linux box running Samba to show up in Network Neighborhood in Windows and to be accessible using `"\\SERVERNAME\"`?**

I read that I need to make the Linux box *the* WINS server for the network by enabling WINS server in Samba, running nmbd on the Linux box, and setting up WINS server in the router's DHCP config. However, I never needed to do that for the other Windows machines and as such I think it's too much. AFAIK `"\\SERVERNAME\"` is resolved using NETBIOS broadcast in the absence of WINS server, so the Linux box should be resolvable from Windows side without messing around with WINS servers.

I would like to know the basic components that make Network Neighborhood work. I don't know much about Windows networking so any simple explanation would be welcome.

The devices are all in the same subnet and my router is running DD-WRT in case that is relevant.